# JQuery autocomplete search using typeahead in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://auto.test/autocomplete?query= 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My Route (web.php):

```
Route::get('search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');
Route::get('autocomplete', 'SearchController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
```

My SearchController:

```
use App\Item;
use Input;
use Responce;

    public function index()
    {
        return view('search');
    }

    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Item::select("name")->where("name", "LIKE", "%{$request->input('name')}%")->get();

        return responce()->json($data);
    }
```

And in my main view (search.blade.php):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Search Name by Auto Complete</h1>
        <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" name="" id="">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";

        $("input.typeahead").typeahead({
            source:function(query, process) {
                return $.get(path, {query:name}, function(data) {
                    return process(data);
                })
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Included are the latest JQuery files and the bootstrap3-typeahead.js from cloudflare. Am I doing something wrong. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: change {query:name} to {name:query} in jQuery get request and check..

Comment: `return $.get(path, {name: query}, function(data) { return process(data) });` still have the same error. Any more work around I may have missed?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing ajax request parameters wrongly. But in your code you expected to receive input parameter 'name' so it could be as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";

        $("input.typeahead").typeahead({
            source:function(query, process) {
                return $.get(path, {name:query}, function(data) {
                    return process(data);
                })
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I did this very code but still get the error. Anything I can further try. I think I'm passing wrong arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I starting using this function today. And I still learning. So... I think you forgot the name and id of your input.

Comment: be more specific about your answer and provide some code solutions